# Deriving probability equation

Tags: probability

Suppose X, Y are discrete random variables with joint probability mass function

$$
f(n) =
\begin{cases}
1/10,  & \text{if $1\leq y\leq x \leq 4$ } \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Solve 
$P(X-Y \geq 1) $:
$$P(X-Y \geq 1) = 1 - P(X=Y) \\ \ since \ P(X<Y) = 0 $$

I am confused how the following probability was derived.
It appears they got the complement of the probability which should equate to 
$$1- P(X-Y < 1) $$
I understand the $P(X<Y)  = 0) $ but I'm not sure how the 1 was pulled out of the probability.

Comment: $1$ wasn't "pulled out". It's simply the complement rule: $P(A) = 1- P(\bar A)$.

Comment: $P(X-Y \geq 1) = P(X > Y) = 1 - P(X \leq Y)$

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin  how does $P(X−Y\geq 1)=P(X>Y)$ shouldn't it  be $P(X−Y\geq 1)=P(X>1+Y)$

Comment: @user $P(X−Y\geq 1)=P(X \geq 1+Y) = P( X > Y)$ because they are discrete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0\leq Z< 1$ means $Z=0$ when $Z$ is an integer.

So... since $\mathsf P(X<Y)=0$

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X-Y\geq 1)~=~&1-\mathsf P(X-Y<1)\\~=~&1-0-\mathsf P(0\leq X-Y<1) \\~=~& 1-\mathsf P(X-Y=0) \\=~& 1-\mathsf P(X=Y)\end{align}$$